# Microsoft Calendar Event Package Config

Tags: azure, go, microsoft-graph-api

```
configuration := &graphconfig.EventsRequestBuilderPostRequestConfiguration{
        Headers: headers,
    }
```

I am not able to get graphconfig package in go

I have tried different different package like msgraph-sdk-go, azure package etc. but didn't get a package for EventsRequestBuilderPostRequestConfiguration{}

Comment: Looks like the package is `github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-go/me`: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-go/blob/main/me/events_request_builder.go

Comment: headers := map[string]string{
  "Prefer": "outlook.timezone=\"Pacific Standard Time\"",
 }
 my header type that way but inside github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-go/me header are type of map[string]map[string]struct{}

Answer (score 0):

We've restructured the package a couple of times since the early days of the preview.

All types for operations under `/me` can now be found in the users sub-package.

Your question is not specific to which endpoint you're trying to query (.../events is available under /me, /users, /groups, ...)

Assuming you're referring to the one under /me or /users, the type **ItemEventsRequestBuilderPostRequestConfiguration** lives under the users sub-package (full import path being `github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-go/users`)

Those changes will becomes less frequent and cease as we reach general availability for the Go SDK. We're also working to get the imports as part of the documentation snippets.